# External SSD drive freezes after a day of IDLE or so

Tags: usb, hard-drive

I've got an external SSD plugged into my Pi with movies to be used for plex, which works great, the problem is I've noticed that after one night or probably more, the system is still seeing the SSD and files, but when I open any file on it or start watching movies via PLEX, the whole system freezes and all apps too as they cannot read from the drive and I cannot eject the drive from the system so I unplug it from the pi and the system goes back to normal, I plug it back in and it works. Is the drive going to sleep somehow?
It is on RaspberryPi 4 with 10.9 version OS. Drive was connected to USB 3 and 2 so it does not matter which usb port.

Comment: Power under-voltage can cause some strange disk issues..

Comment: well it is a small ssd disk, how am i supposed to give it more voltage? It works well if I use it all day, like listening to youtube, music, watching plex. But as soon as I put everything on idle and go to sleep, it won't work the following day

Comment: Typically a powered USB hub or a powered USB disk adapter..   Do a search for 'Powered USB 3.0 Disk adapter' on Amazon etc..

Comment: Of course it might be something else, But I had a similar issue with my RPI4 based media solution at home.   Worked fine for weeks then suddenly it would hang, reboot fail to boot etc.    As soon as I plugged in a different power supply the problems went away.

Comment: Although, I would've expected the power issue to happen under load, when being used and not when idling? I'll have a look for that solution anyway.

Comment: Lot of factors can influence under voltage or even spikes in the power supply which cause glitches and crashes on the computer.